# How to Parcel a List<T> generic?

Tags: android, arraylist, parcel

Having a `List<T> list;`. Where `T extends Parcelable`. Does anyone knows how to read the list from a Parcel??

I'm adding the List with:
`parcel.writeTypedList(list);`

To read the list from the parcel I need to know the final object class, but I don't have it because it's a generic List.

Thanks!

Comment: I did not understand what you wanted. You can still read the class of every element. And from Java 9, you will be able to get the generic type at runtime.

Comment: It's a Android problem, trying to Serialize an Object using Parcelable.

Using `readList(List outVal, ClassLoader loader)` I need the ClassLoader of the class <T>. How can I get the ClassLoader from a generic type?
For example I can do
Table.class.getClassLoader(); or Person.class.getClassLoader();

But I can't do T.class.getClassLoader();